# Integration and a new variabe - newbie question

Tags: calculus, integration

I have come across an integrl where they introduce a new variable $k' = k - k_0$ where $k_0 = \text{const}$.

$$
\begin{split}
\psi(x) &= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{(k-k_0)^2}{2 \sigma_x^2}} e^{ikx} \,\,\mathrm{d}k\\
\boxed{\scriptsize k' = k-k_0} &\Longrightarrow \boxed{\scriptsize k=k' - k_0} \Longrightarrow\boxed{{\scriptsize \mathrm{d}k = \ ???}}\\
\psi(x) &= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{- k'^2 / 2 \sigma_x^2} \, e^{i(k' -k_0)x} \,\,\mathrm{d}k'\\
\end{split}
$$

I am nt sure how did an author get $\mathrm{d}k'$ out of $\mathrm{d}k$ so i need you to confirm my take on this. If i differentiate a new variable i get:

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{d k'}{dk} &= \frac{d k}{d k} - \frac{d k_0}{dk}\\
\frac{d k'}{dk} &= \frac{d k}{d k}\\
\end{split}
$$

**Am i allowed to just cancel out the $dk$ in the denominator to get the below?**

$$
dk' = dk
$$

Comment: Note that $\frac{dk}{dk}=1$ (we are **not** cancelling). As to whether you can replace $dk$ by $dk'$, the short answer is yes. And it is not really cancellation, but explaining what it is would take an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Oh i see so the proper way would be $\frac{dk'}{dk} = 1$ and therefore $dk' = dk$. I knew i was doing somthing wrong. Thank you. Please write an anwser so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\boxed{\scriptsize k=k' - k_0} \Longrightarrow\boxed{{\scriptsize \mathrm{d}k = \ ???}}$

When you have the first equation, derive each side by k, left side would be $\mathrm{d}k$, right side would be $\mathrm{d}k'$ and $k_0$ is just a constant so derivative would be zero. New equation would be:

$\boxed{\mathrm{d}k=\mathrm{d}k'}$

P.S. Sorry for bad language.